# como obtener toDataURL Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Tengo un problema con mi canvas, estoy pintando una imagen en base64 y quiero sacarla luego de pintarla en el canvas, al utilizar toDataURL esta me muestra un base64 q corresponde a una imagen negra.
dejo mi codigo actual gracias.

```
  var imgData = e.target.result;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(image, canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2);
  };
  image.src = imgData;
  var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  this.imageData = imageURL;
```

Comment: soy novato en esto de canvas no estoy seguro si var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); va dentro de image.onload = function()

Comment: lo es que he notado es que si vuelvo a enviar la misma imagen o otro a la 2da vez si funciona me muestra el base64 de la imagen correcta no el fondo negro

Answer (score 0):

No se si todavía te interesa cómo obtener data:uri de canvas. Las cosas van así: primero necesitas "pintar" algo en el canvas, después conviertes el canvas a data:uri utilizando el método `.toDataURL()`. Puedes recuperar el url y utilizarlo por ejemplo como el valor del atributo src de una imagen.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#2BA6CB";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      // cuerpo
      ctx.scale(.6, .6);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(8, 6);
      ctx.lineTo(1, 6);
      ctx.lineTo(1, 16);
      ctx.lineTo(11, 16);
      ctx.lineTo(11, 9);
      //flecha
      ctx.moveTo(5, 9);
      ctx.lineTo(11, 3);
      ctx.lineTo(8, 1);
      ctx.lineTo(16, 1);
      ctx.lineTo(16, 9);
      ctx.lineTo(14, 6);
      ctx.lineTo(8, 12);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();

      var url = canvas.toDataURL();

      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = url;
      document.getElementById("img").src = url;
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<p>canvas: </p>
<canvas width="11" height="12" id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
<p>imagen: </p>
<img alt="data:uri test" id="img" width="11" height="12" src="noImg">
```

Este es un ejemplo de [Crear data:uri desde canvas](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/toDataURL.php)